# Using a Factorial Function on an Array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, compiler-errors, factorial

Im trying to get my factorial function to go through all the numbers in my array and give me the result but I keep getting an error message. Any idea what im doing wrong? Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Recursion.h"

int factorial(int n)
{

if (n == 0)
       return 1;
   else
       return n * factorial(n-1);
}

int main()
{
    int my_list[5] = {2, 4, 6, 8, 10};

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        int b = factorial(my_list[i]);
        std::cout << b << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: You have a stray semicolon at the end of the program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is designed to take a single integer, and not an array. Iterate over the array, and call the method on each int within the array

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    int b = factorial(my_list[i]);
    std::cout << b << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: I've iterated over the array now but the build still failed. I got this error: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: I had to remove the include "Recursion.h", but the code compiles and executes properly: https://godbolt.org/z/y_jbF-

Comment: To second @robthebloke, unless to have an actual head file called ```recursion.h```, you don't need to use an ```include``` statement. C++ supports recursion.